# How can pass values between events?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I've a `Dropdownlist` and a button inside a datalist. I choose the number of items from dropdownlist and then pass it to the button event to send it to the database.

But I'm unable to do so. The problem is the variable `selectedValue` gets assigned only inside `dditem_change`, although I've declared it globally.

How can I access its value in `DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)`.

Here is the code for dropdown list change

```
public void dditem_change(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ddlList = (DropDownList)sender;
        selectedValue = ((DropDownList)ddlList.NamingContainer.FindControl("drplist")).SelectedValue;
    }
```

This is the code for public void DataList1_ItemCommand

```
public void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName == "Add")
    {
        if (Session["user"] == null)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Login First!!!');</script>");

        }
        else
        {

            string[] ar = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(',');
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DTPXP-77A;Initial Catalog=practice;Integrated Security=true";
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into cart values(@username,@prodname,@price,@stock)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@prodname", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@price", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@stock", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters["@username"].Value = Session["user"].ToString();
            cmd.Parameters["@prodname"].Value = ar[0].ToString();
            cmd.Parameters["@price"].Value = int.Parse(ar[1]);
            cmd.Parameters["@stock"].Value = //selectedValue NOT ACCESSIBLE//
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Successfully Added');</script>");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you use the ddlList.SelectedValue inside DataList1_ItemCommand?

Comment: Could you show how it is declared and where in the context of the page class?

Comment: No I cannot Access ddlList.SelectedValue inside DataList1_ItemCommand

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of the [ASP.NET page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28VS.100%29.aspx). When you select the drop down menu this causes a postback in which you store your `selectedValue` variable. When you then trigger the button that causes *another* postback which results in your `selectedValue` being lost as the page is re-created.

In order to persist the value between postbacks you need to store it somewhere. For example, you could use `Session` storage e.g.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        selectedValue = (string)Session["SelectedValue"];
    }
}

public void dditem_change(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ddlList = (DropDownList)sender;
    Session["SelectedValue"] = ((DropDownList)ddlList.NamingContainer.FindControl("drplist")).SelectedValue;
}

public void DataList1_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // selectedValue should now be accessible
}
```

Considering how small the data is, and given it is in-fact *view* specific, it might be better placed in the [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx).

Comment: You were right I made a Session["value"] = selectedValue; and retrieved its value. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Why you don't read the value directly where you need it?
In this case you wouldn't need to store anything in the "selectedValue" variable. Something like:

```
cmd.Parameters["@stock"].Value = 
   ((DropDownList)FindControl("drpList")).SelectedValue;
```

EDIT: I added the cast to DropDownList.